# Android XML parsing

Tags: xml, android, parsing, nullpointerexception

A strange problem has cropped up... I checked several websites but couldn't find anything wrong with the code... But it returns `NullPointerException`...

```
try { 

    SAXParserFactory f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = f.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
    reader.setContentHandler(handler);
    System.out.println(uri_this);
    reader.parse(new InputSource(url_this.openStream())); // i get nullpointerexception here 

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

In the catch statement I have caught `NullPointerException` and made it print the error.

The `ContentHandler` is fine because I have got parsed files for small files but for larger files, it doesn't seem to work. What is the problem? Or do I need some buffering for larger files? I'm clueless and have tried all possibilities except buffering because I don't know the coding for that.

I figured out 1 thing: the object of the input source is freed before the `reader.parse` can finish. I don't understand why it's happening.

The `LogCat` gives the following (only the erroneous part):

```
01-06 15:12:27.145: INFO/System.out(319): http://mywebsite.com/products_xml.php?cPath=43
01-06 15:12:31.094: DEBUG/dalvikvm(319): GC freed 4031 objects / 203424 bytes in 189ms
01-06 15:12:31.505: DEBUG/dalvikvm(100): GC freed 3326 objects / 190192 bytes in 283ms
01-06 15:12:34.274: DEBUG/dalvikvm(319): GC freed 1153 objects / 80432 bytes in 146ms
01-06 15:12:34.646: INFO/System.out(319): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm getting the url "url_this" 4m the constructor as arguments.

Comment: Could you paste the full stack of the NPE?

Comment: Also, have you checked if any of the references, in the allegedly erroneous statement, is null?

Comment: yes samuh i have checked and m confident bout that... coz as i informed earlier... its running perfectly for smaller files about 1page worth of xml... but it returns null for others

Comment: You did not say you actually checked url is not null. Being confident is not the same as knowing.

Comment: i checked perfectly... the url is not null...

Comment: reader.setContentHandler(handler); -- I don't see 'handler' being defined anywhere. Please post complete code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanx all of u. I got my mistake. actually in 1 case there was no text between start and end tag... hence the variable i stored text in was null... i called .toString() on that. resulting in an exception - NullPointerException. Thanx all 4 ur help.

Answer (score 2):

There not enough info to help you here but did you notice that you print out a variable called **uri_this** in the shell but dereference **url** to be parsed? So just because the logfile shows *http://mywebsite.com/products_xml.php?cPath=43* it does not automatically mean, that the variable **url** is initialized and also contains that string.

Or it could be that the openStream() method on the url object (whatever type it is) returns null in some conditions and InputSource can not handle being passed null in the constructor. As I said - there is not enough info in the short snipplet to solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanx Valentin. Actually i myself was xonfused on wat to post here. coz i had global definitions and a lot of code in between the snippet i hsve pasted. Thanx 4 ur valuable comments...

Answer (score 0):

I just released a library to make XML parsing on Android 10x easier than it currently is. It is a very small abstraction layer that sits on top of the existing xml pull parsing libraries provided by the runtime and allow you to use simple xpath-like paths to elements to get parsed values back.

Performance impact is almost nothing on top of the existing parse operation, it is a very simple/clean implementation:
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/simple-java-xml-parser-sjxp/

Answer (score 0):

check the above Url http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

changes made in  XMLParser.java

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

it will works InshaAllah...